# How do I replace all characters with a symbol after the first occurrence without affecting capitalization?

Tags: python, string, character

I cannot figure out how to replace all incidences of the first character, not including the first character without affecting the originally capitalization. For example, I want to turn She's The Best On The Sea to, She'$ The Be$t On The $ea. What is the most efficient way to go about doing this.

I have tried using .title() without success and have received botched output with capitalization in the wrong characters.

```
def change(s):
    news=s.lower()
    firstchar=news[0]
    modifieds=news[1:].replace(firstchar,"$")
    final=(firstchar+modifieds)
    print(final.title())

change("She's The Best On The Sea")
```

She'$ The Be$T On The $Ea

Comment: Complicated but clean solution: Use regular expressions ("re" module). Simple solution: Don't use "lower" (and later "title" on whole string but replace "firstchar.upper()" and then "firstchar.lower()" by the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` with `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
import re

s = "She's The Best On The Sea"
s[0] + re.sub('s', '$', s[1:], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Output:

```
"She'$ The Be$t On The $ea"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a readable way:

```
text = "She's The Best On The Sea"

new_text = ""
string_to_check = "s"
replacement = "$"

for i in range(len(text)):
    if i != 0 and text[i].lower() == string_to_check:
        new_text += replacement
    else:
        new_text += text[i]

print(new_text)
```

Output:

```
She'$ The Be$t On The $ea
```